# C# XmlSerializer trim whitespaces

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xml-serialization

I've trouble trimming strings when using the [`XmlSerializer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer(v=vs.110).aspx), when using a XmlReader. The IgnoreWhitespace option shows no effect and the element string still contains \n and whitespaces.

Is there any way to trim it "on the fly"?
I would prefer such a method since I deserialize into an array of strings

Here's an example xml:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<root>
  <element>
    some random string
  </element>
  <element>
    another random string
  </element>
</root>"
```

And here's the example code:

```
class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string xml =
            @"<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
            <root>
              <element>
                 some random string
              </element>
                <element>
                 another random string
              </element>
            </root>";

            var string_reader = new StringReader(xml);

            var xml_reader = XmlReader.Create(string_reader, new XmlReaderSettings()
            {
                IgnoreWhitespace = true //setting this option doesn't work
            });
            root d = (root)new XmlSerializer(typeof(root)).Deserialize(xml_reader);
            d.elements[0].Contains("\n"); //true

            //Dispose string/xml reader

            Console.Read();
        }
    }

    public class root
    { 
        [XmlElement(ElementName ="element")]
        public string[] elements { set; get; }
    }
```

Comment: The IgnoreWhiteSpace property is for reading XML, and ignoring any white space between elements and attributes. It's not going to trim the whitespace out of your element values. More info here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreadersettings.ignorewhitespace(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I see, thank you. Do you know what I could use for this scenario?

Comment: Just loop through the root.elements array after reading the XML File, and manually trim the whitespace out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After reading in the XML file, you need to manually trim out the whitespace

```
root d = (root)new XmlSerializer(typeof(root)).Deserialize(xml_reader);
for (int i = 0; i < d.elements.Count; i++)
{
  d.elements[i] = d.elements[i].Replace("\n", String.Empty).Trim();
}
```